# nodejs driver - reconnect slow when PRIMARY GOES DOWN

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-replication, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I want to know how does nodejs driver behave when PRIMARY GOES DOWN.

Issue db.shutdownServer() on Primary "SECONDARY" become Primary right away.
But driver takes at least 11 second hanging before issuing another write command again.

I test with various number for connectTimeoutMS & socketTimeoutMS & haInterval
But it does not help.

Connection String:

```
"mongodb://xxx:xxx@1.10.21.67:27017,1.10.21.98:27017/test?replicaSet=hhawsmongo&poolSize=1&autoReconnect=true&reconnectTries=100&connectTimeoutMS=1000&socketTimeoutMS=1000&haInterval=500&forceServerObjectId=true"
```

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-973

Comment: Are you sure that the secondary becomes primary _right away_? Typically it takes a few seconds for the nodes to be sure that there is a communication problem, to agree to holding a new election, to elect a node to be primary, and for that node to transition.

Comment: I can see with rs.status() 
it may take a couple of seconds. But driver takes more then 10 seconds. But they make it critical issue. So I believe I am right :) and they are trying to fix